# Proving a probability transition matrix

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following question:
[image]

With the necessary show that proof:
[image]

My solution, states 'shown in class' but we were never taught how to derive this. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the probability that the molecule that passes through the aperture goes from A to B?

Comment: I haven't been told that - but I do know this is a markov chain, that is the only extra info we have.

Comment: All of the information that you need to compute this probability is in the problem statement. You shouldn’t have to be told what it is.

Comment: I'm asking for a bit of help - my lecturers make numerous mistakes. A response like yours really isn't very helpful or necessary.

Comment: If there are $i$ molecules in container A, then how many are there in container B?  If a molecule is chosen uniformly at random, what is the probability that it is in container A?

Comment: The way you’ve expressed both your question and your comment, it seems like you’re just throwing your hands up and saying “I have no idea how to approach this problem. This looks nothing like anything I had in my lectures.” I’d bet that you really do have all of the necessary tools to solve it, but you’ve convinced yourself that you don’t. The key is in the previous comment by saulspatz. Observe, too, that only one molecule moves at a time, so the number of them in A can only go up or down by one at each step.

Comment: Interestingly the resources provided to me are littered with mistakes, which I spend the majority of my time trying to rectify - which is why I use a site like this to help me grasp certain concepts which have been taught incorrectly. Again there's no need to assume I have the 'necessary tools', when you have no idea what resources I have or whether they are accurate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the problem let X_n be the number of molecules in container A after n units of time have passed. 
Now clearly the state space is S={0,1,...,N} since at some point in time, container A can have all the molecules or none of the molecules. 
Now we can consider, by homogeneity of the problem what happens if X_0=0, that is there are 0 molecules in A. If this is the case then once the aperture opens, only one molecule can go from B to A, so P(X_1=1|X_0=0)=1 in terms of transition probabilities. Now consider what happens if X_0=1 (i.e we have 1 molecule in A). In this case once the aperture opens, one molecule (out of N) can go from A to B with probability 1/N or one molecule (from N-1 possibilities in B) can go from B to A with probability (N-1)/N. So P(X_1=0|X_0=1)=1/N (molecule goes from A to B) and P(X_1=2|X_0=1)=(N-1)/N (molecule goes from B to A). 
Now continue with this process to get the remaining transition probabilities noting that if there are N molecules in A, then only one molecule can go from A to B once this aperture opens.

Comment: Just found this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48129/calculating-transition-probabilities-for-ehrenfest-diffusion

Comment: Thank you so much!!